# How to display full path of ALL currently running process in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any method to display all currently running process full path and save in variable or list in C#?

I use "tasklist". But it only display process name and ID and nothing else...
and also I tried `Process.GetProcesses()`, but I'munable to fetch full path.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
Console.WriteLine(processlist);
foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Process: {0}\t\t\t\t\t\t ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
  Console.WriteLine(theprocess);
}
Console.ReadKey()
```

I expect full path of running process like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\example.exe` if example.exe is running on that time.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`MainModule.FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename?view=netframework-4.8) located on the [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
string fullPath = theprocess.MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: Note to all and sundry, `MainModule` is likely to throw an exception in a good subset of circumstances and needs to be used with the appropriate fault tolerance. best read the documentation